# LaTex: Making a 3x2 panel with arrows in between

Tags: latex, tablelayout

I am trying to make the following 3x2 panel layout with arrows for a figure using latex:

[image: 3x2 panel with arrows in between]

I am using the `graphicx` and `subcaption` packages at the moment and ideally would only add new packages that are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to make pdf files from 8 images I had. I think with little bit modification this will work for you. My latex doesnt have arrow that you're looking for. So you have to add them.

```
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\usepackage{graphicx}
\\usepackage{subcaption}
\\setlength{\\voffset}{-0.75in}
\\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
\n
\\begin{document} 
\\begin{figure} 
\\begin{center}
\\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\\huge \\textbf{Title} 
\\end{center} 
\\begin{tabular}{lp{11cm}} 
\\hfill  & \Large   \\textbf{Name} \Large\hfill     \\textbf{%s}
\\end{tabular} 
\\hspace*{-3cm} 
\\begin{subfigure}{0.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig1} 
\\end{subfigure}%% 
\\hspace{1.5in} 
\\begin{subfigure}{0.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig2} 
\\end{subfigure} 
\\hspace*{-3cm} 
\\begin{subfigure}{0.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig1} 
\\end{subfigure}%% 
\\hspace{1.5in} 
\\begin{subfigure}{0.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig2} 
\\end{subfigure} 
\\hspace*{-3cm} 
\\begin{subfigure}{.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig1} 
\\end{subfigure}%% 
\\hspace{1.5in} 
\\begin{subfigure}{.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig2} 
\\end{subfigure} 

\\hspace*{-3cm} 
\\begin{subfigure}{.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig1} 
\\end{subfigure}%% 
\\hspace{1.5in} 
\\begin{subfigure}{.5\\textwidth} 
\\centering 
\\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{%s} 
\\label{fig:sfig2} 
\\end{subfigure} 

\\end{figure}
\\end{document}
```